# Insert a fullpage landscape figure without having to manually cut text

Tags: landscape

I have a document with a lot of text and I want a fullpage landscape figure to be inserted somewhere in the middle. I have two options:

- Use a normal figure and rotate it, but this makes it annoying to read the PDF
- Use `\begin{landscape}` and `\end{lanscape}` but then I have to "cut" the text by placing those myself.

Is there some way to have the landscape page behave as a figure and automagically insert itself somewhere instead of starting a new page when I write `\begin{landscape}` and ending it when I write `\end{lanscape}`?

I tried putting `\begin{landscape}` and `\end{lanscape}` inside a figure but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use package `afterpage`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\afterpage{%
  \begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}%
      \rule{\linewidth}{\textheight}%
    \end{figure}
  \end{landscape}%
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]